# Concatenate two columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to concatenate two `date` columns, putting a `-` between the values.

Table:

```
Column A                | Column B
------------------------|-------------------------
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL
NULL                    | 2011-01-12 00:00:00.000
2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2010-05-31 00:00:00.000
NULL                    | NULL
```

Query:

```
select L.ColumnA + ' - ' + L.Column B AS [Dates] 
from abc L
```

It's showing all the fields NULL unless both the columns have some data like

```
2006-04-01 00:00:00.000-2010 - 05-31 00:00:00.000
```

However, the final output I need is:

```
[Dates]
--------------------
07/01/10 - 
04/01/06 - 05/31/10
 - 01/12/11
<blank (for nulls)>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert NULL values to empty strings. At the very least:

```
SELECT COALESCE(L.ColumnA, '') + '-' + COALESCE(L.ColumnB, '') AS [Dates] 
    FROM abc L
```

Then, to format the dates as shown:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), L.ColumnA, 1), '') + '-' 
     + COALESCE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), L.ColumnB, 1), '') AS [Dates] 
    FROM abc L
```

Comment: Thanks for replying me....I tried this code it worked but its getting wrong values...wherever there is NULL in both the columns it should show NULL but by default it is showing 01/01/00-01/01/00 and more over where it is Null in that place by default it is assuming 01/01/00...

Comment: @Shahsra: So you actually want your output to look like this? `07/01/10 - NULL`, `NULL - 01/12/11`, `04/01/06 - 05/31/10`, `NULL - NULL`

Comment: I just modified my output...yeah almost same which you have mentioned above...instead of NULL I just need blank space..No NULL OR nothing it should '03/01/07 -  ' ...empty space...

Comment: No Joe..its not working in that way which I mentioned in my output result. Your code is working like this: 03/01/07 - 01/01/00. Instead of blankspace it is showing '01/01/00'.

Comment: @Shahsra: Strange. I've edited my answer to reverse the order of operations. See if that works any better for you.

Comment: Really you are genius... I donno how you guys do all these...really you guys are damn good. Thanks a lot Joe its wroking perfectly..Really appreciate it...